# Turtle graphics snake game

Tags: python, python-3.4, turtle-graphics

I just started turtle graphics yesterday. I decided to make a little snake game in turtle graphics. But later on, I got some problems after another. :(
The problem is that, I couldn't level up the game whenever my snake eats the food :( and the movement of my snake is a little bit not the same to the typical snake game... so I'm here to ask for suggestions what to do to solve these problems. so please lend me your ideas :D

well, here's my very long long code..

```
from turtle import *
import random

title("Snake Game")     #title of the game

setup(555,555)  #sets the screensize into 555x555 px

bgcolor("orange")   #background color

#pressed key functions
def up():
    penup()
    pendown()
    head(90)


def right():
    penup()
    pendown()
    head(0)

def left():
    penup()
    pendown()
    head(180)

def down():
    penup()
    pendown()
    head(270)


#draw dot
def dotx():
    pen2.penup()
    pen2.goto(x1,y1)
    pen2.pendown()
    pen2.dot(20,"green")

#heading of the snake
def head(x):
    for i in range(9999999):
        for ii in range(20):
            seth(x)
            fd(2)
            if xcor()>=250.0 or ycor()>=250.0 or xcor()<=-250.0 or ycor()<=-250.0:
                clear()
                pen2.clear()
                pen4.write("GAME OVER")
                break
            elif (xcor() in x2) and (ycor() in y2):
                pen2.clear()
                pen4.write("EATEN",False,'center',font=('Arial',15,'normal'))
        if xcor()>=250.0 or ycor()>=250.0 or xcor()<=-250.0 or ycor()<=-250.0:
            clear()
            pen2.clear()
            pen4.write("GAME OVER")
            break
        clear()


color("white")
pensize(5)  #pensize

shape('turtle')

#hideturtle()


delay(2)    #delay of animation
speed(10)    #speed of animation

pen2=Pen()  #dots
pen2.hideturtle()

pen4=Pen()
pen4.hideturtle()
pen4.color("white")

#border
pen3=Pen()
pen3.color("white")
pen3.pensize(3)
pen3.hideturtle()
pen3.speed(10)
pen3.penup()
pen3.goto(-250,-250)
pen3.pendown()
for p3 in range(4):
    pen3.fd(500)
    pen3.left(90)


#dots coordinates

x1=random.randint(-225,225)
y1=random.randint(-225,225)
x2=list(range(x1-6,x1+6))
y2=list(range(y1-6,y1+6))


dotx()  #call dots


#controls
onkey(up,"Up")
onkey(right,"Right")
onkey(left,"Left")
onkey(down,"Down")
listen()
```

Comment: Why not use Pygame or a similar game engine? Methods of exhaustion is so ancient. This is the likes of Archimedes, don't do work you don't have to. That's what computers are for.

Comment: actually, that is a project.
our teacher asked us to make a game out of turtle graphics :3
she wont even listen, even I suggest pygame :3

Answer (score 0):

To make the snake grow I find it easy to create a list and use pop and insert functions to have a constant list of all of the snake locations. Then you can use turtles stamp method to stamp all of these list locations so that it displays in all locations. Here's an example of a turtle snake game I made a while ago so you can see how to use these concepts

```
        pos.insert(0,[round((snake.xcor())),round((snake.ycor()))])      #round x turns the float value of position into integer
        pos.pop(-1)
        for x in range(1, len(pos)):
            if pos[x] == pos[0]:
               sys.exit()
            elif pos[x]!= pos[0]:
                pass;
        #pop removes last element of list, used to update position
    else:                                      #insert inserts an element into list at position
        pos.insert(0,[round((snake.xcor())),round((snake.ycor()))])
```

Comment: Rather than giving your whole code, please confine your code to just answering the specific issues the question raised.